# using python variable in django sql query

Tags: python, django

```
    @staticmethod
    def getdata(backdays):
        cursor = connections['MMY'].cursor()
        query ="Select * from temp WHERE DAY_OF_MONTH=TO_CHAR(sysdate-?,'DD')"
        cursor.execute(query,(backdays))
        rdict = namedtuplefetchall(cursor)
        return rdict
```

i am getting attribute error , I can see this value is getting printed when i am using print but above is failing can any one please help . it is python . Value is being passed using  axios in javascript .

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in the Django framework then , according to me instead of firing query in a model file, you go for using the "for loop iterations" in views.py file.

Comment: I got the way to get it and pass it to model from view.